# Prevent grid area size increase / decrease when user zooms browser

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a layout which has decorative borders ( top, right, bottom, left ), these borders do not contain content, but do contain ornate SVG patterns.

These borders are being defined using the `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` `grid` properties, and have a height or width of 70px.

When a user sets their browser zoom level to 125%, 150%, 200% the size of the element scales proportionately ( 87px, 105px, 140px )

How do I prevent some grid areas ( top, right, bottom, left ) from growing / shrinking based on user's browser zoom input.

```
.stage-inner {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70px 1fr 1fr 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr 1fr 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "top top top top top"
    "left content content content right"
    "left content content content right"
    "left content content content right"
    "bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom";
}
```

https://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/bzBdmX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try accessing the device pixel ratio and divide your dimension by that percentage to recalculate a dimension that will render at 70px.

```
browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
```

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/GzNZZd

I forked your codepen and added this jQuery code:

```
$( window ).on( 'load resize', function() {
    const browserZoomLevel = Math.round(window.devicePixelRatio * 100);
    const normalizedDimension = 70 * 100 / browserZoomLevel + 'px';

    $( '.stage-inner' )
        .css( 
            'gridTemplateColumns', 
            normalizedDimension + ' 1fr 1fr 1fr ' + normalizedDimension 
        ).css(
           'gridTemplateRows', 
            normalizedDimension + ' 1fr 1fr 1fr ' + normalizedDimension 
    );
});
```

Comment: Works pretty good -- thanks for the suggestion. Was hoping for a plain CSS solution, but it looks like the device pixel ratio media queries aren't standard yet.

Comment: Oh by the way -- the above math works out wonky -- renders at 35px instead of 70px. Not a big deal, the concept worked out.